# How to check if a thread is already started or not in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am having a class which extends *Thread*.

I will start the thread at some point.

After some time I need to check if that thread is already started or not?

So that I can start the thread at that particular point.

My thread class will be,

```
public class BasicChatListener extends Thread{

    public void run(){


    }

}
```

I need the know the particular thread of a `BasicChatListener` class is running or not ?
Because I have multiple threads are already running in my application.

How our stack members will help me.

Comment: You held the reference to the specified `BasicChatListener`, don't you?

Comment: Looks like you need to create a start just one listener. Can you create instance of the `BasicChatListener` and start it at the same time?

Comment: @Vignesh Vino But How to refer the `BasicChatListener` thread particularly for checking ? Even I can have multiple threads in my application ? That is what I have asked.

Comment: I need the know the particular thread of a class is running or not ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Thread.getState()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getState%28%29) and use the corresponding [states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html).

Note that by the time you read this state *it may have changed*, but you may be able to determine something of interest. Check out [this state diagram](http://bighai.com/ppjava/?p=144) for the available transitions.

Comment: How to refer the `BasicChatListener` thread particularly for check ?

Comment: It is probably better to use a Monitor, Semaphore, or some other shared object as the Thread states are a tad limited. Running may not mean started to the degree you want.

Comment: Link not working!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Use either [Thread#isAlive()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive%28%29)

```
if (Thread.currentThread().isAlive())
```

JavaDoc says:

> Tests if this thread is alive. A thread is alive if it has been started and has not yet died.

Or, use [Thread#getState()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getState%28%29) as

```
Thread.State currState = Thread.currentThread().getState();
if (currState != Thread.State.NEW && currState != Thread.State.TERMINATED)
```

JavaDoc says:

> Returns the state of this thread. This method is designed for use in monitoring of the system state, not for synchronization control.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it with [isAlive](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive%28%29)..

`isAlive` tests if this thread is alive. A thread is alive if it has been started and has not yet died.

Comment: +1 To me, using isAlive is clearer than calling getState and having to check that the state is not new.

Answer (score 1):

I use this code `Thread.isAlive()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GetState()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getState%28%29)

> Returns the state of this thread. This method is designed for use in monitoring of the system state, not for synchronization control.

or boolean  [isAlive()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive%28%29)

> Tests if this thread is alive. A thread is alive if it has been started and has not yet died.

Answer (score 1):

[Thread.isAlive()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive%28%29) can determine if a thread is running.

> Tests if this thread is alive. A thread is alive if it has been started and has not yet died.

[Thread#getState()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getState%28%29); can return the exact state of a thread.

> Returns the state of this thread. This method is designed for use in monitoring of the system state, not for synchronization control.